# PostgreSQL wrong ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.4

I'll preface this with the fact that I haven't used PostgreSQL much.  I tried using it with RoR but the fact that it uses an ORM, I never got *why* PostgreSQL was the flavor of choice.

After fighting with getting the damn thing installed on Ubuntu 14.04, I need to clone a repo that depends on it.

After about 30 minutes of dealing trying a few things, I discovered:

```
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf 
LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.auto.conf"
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-2] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main" has wrong ownership
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-3] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-4] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 before_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-5] DEBUG:  shmem_exit(1): 0 on_shmem_exit callbacks to make
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-6] DEBUG:  proc_exit(1): 0 callbacks to make
2015-02-14 21:05:01 PST [7665-7] DEBUG:  exit(1)
```

One, I don't know what this `auto.conf` file it's looking for as I'm specifying the conf file.

However... (edited to what I think are the appropriate line[s])

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/postgresql/9.4/main/pg_hba.conf 

local   all             postgres        127.0.0.1               peer
```

(I added in the local IP after nothing working.  Still doesn't work.)

And (`/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/`)

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   315 Feb 14 20:20 environment
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   143 Feb 14 20:20 pg_ctl.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  4641 Feb 14 20:55 pg_hba.conf
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  4641 Feb 14 20:20 pg_hba.conf~
-rw-r----- 1 postgres postgres  1636 Feb 14 20:20 pg_ident.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres 21461 Feb 14 20:20 postgresql.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 postgres postgres   378 Feb 14 20:20 start.conf
```

Seems to me the configuration files are owned by `postgres`.  What gives?

#### Update (9:30p)

Running the following command (as `postgres`) gives the same result.

```
$ su - postgres; /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/postgres -d 3 -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.4/main/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: You display ownership of the files in an undisclosed directory, but the error complains about `data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main" has wrong ownership`. Also, did you make sure you are tryng to start the server as the system user `postgres`?

Comment: Edited. My bad on not disclosing the directory. Edited.

Comment: OK, but who owns the data *directory*? What do you get for `ls -la`in  `/var/lib/postgresql/9.4` and `/var/lib/postgresql`?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error message, ownership for the data directory seems to be misconfigured. If so, fix with (as privileged system user):

```
chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4
chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main
```

Use the "recursive" option `-R` if anything inside those directories is owned by different users.